# Saving a particular Objects property in localstorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, javascript-objects

The standard

```
localStorage.var = var;
```

Isn't working for me, for example:

```
localStorage.library_science1.owned = library_science1.owned;
```

Where library_science1 is a previously created Object with the 'owned' property. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Keep in mind that `localStorage` only stores strings. Please see [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2010892/218196).

Answer (score 0):

Local storage only handles Strings.  Use `JSON.stringify(library_science1)` before you store, and `JSON.parse(localStorage.library_science1)` when you read from localStorage.